# How to use two value in the last row of a table to add rows to another table with Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, datatables

I am new to vba and having a little trouble figuring this out. Don't really know where to start

I have two tables. I'm simply just trying to find code to say that if the last row in table 1 of worksheet 1 has any value in the 2nd column and the value in the last column is greater than 1 then take the value in the last column of the last row and add that many rows to table 2 of worksheet 2.

I tried searching other posts for this same type of topic but couldn't find any. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with table? an [excel structured table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)? or just a range?

Comment: Hello Ricardo. Thanks for replying!. I'm talking about an Excel structured table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to a standard module

You could validate if the last column last row value is a number. I'm assuming that it is.

**Code:**

```
Public Sub AddRowsToTable()

    Dim sourceTable As ListObject
    Dim targetTable As ListObject

    Set sourceTable = Range("Table1").ListObject
    Set targetTable = Range("Table2").ListObject

    Dim valueSecondCol As Variant
    Dim valueLastRowLastCol As Long

    ' Get last row, second column value
    valueSecondCol = sourceTable.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Cells(sourceTable.ListRows.Count).Value

    ' Get last row, last column value
    valueLastRowLastCol = sourceTable.ListColumns(sourceTable.ListColumns.Count).DataBodyRange.Cells(sourceTable.ListRows.Count).Value

    ' Exit if it's null
    If valueSecondCol = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    ' Add as many rows as the number in last column, last row of source table to target table
    targetTable.Resize targetTable.HeaderRowRange.Resize(targetTable.ListRows.Count + valueLastRowLastCol + 1)

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: YES IT WORKED GREAT! You've given me back some hope! Could you help me take this one step further and I think ill have it all worked out. Is it possible to execute this code only when a new line is added to the source table? What I did was I added a command button to execute the code you gave me. But if I keep hitting the button it will continue to add new lines to the target table. I am just trying to account for click happy people or user error.

Comment: Awesome. Please remember to mark the answer (check mark at the left) so others may find it. I’m not at my computer, but look for `sheet_change` event